# Does anyone know if it is possible to set an HTML image map and have links in one part of the map jump you to links on other parts of the same map?

Tags: html, css, imagemap

So the goal here is to have an image map setup using HTML that allows for linking from one part of the image to another part inside the same image. What I am facing here is all the information is in the same infographic which is like three pages of scrolling to move through. Can I set a link at the top of an image and have it jump down to another part of the same image?

I have a work around with the single infographic is broken into several graphics stacked and than additional maps set up for the individual images but its ugly. I have a cut down example of what I am working with below. Is there a way to have the links image2 or image3 shown below target inside the same image and not have to target individual images like what currently shown?

```
<div><img src="https://tfstest.service-now.com/sys_attachment.do?sys_id=4beacd3bdb489304c84b782bbf96197f" alt="" usemap="#Map" /> <map id="Map" name="Map"> 
<area title="" alt="" coords="28,133,525,155" shape="rect" href="#image2" />
<area title="" alt="" coords="29,160,237,178" shape="rect" href="#image3" />
<area title="" alt="" coords="28,180,330,201" shape="rect" href="#image4" />
</map></div>
 <div><a id="image2"></a><img style="align: baseline;" src="attachment.do?sys_id=c7" /></div>
    <div><a id="image3"></a><img style="align: baseline;" src="attachment.do?sys_id=93" /></div>
    <div><a id="image4"></a> <img style="align: baseline;" src="attachment.do?sys_id=97" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.myclass {
        position: absolute;
        width: 6%;
        height: 9.5%;
        z-index: 1;
        background-color: red;
        border-radius: 15px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/730803/pexels-photo-730803.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb" style="width: 100%;height: 100%"/>
 
 <p class="highlight"></p>
 <a href="#2" title="Point 1 Pointer is here" style="left: 5vw;top: 23.6%;" class="myclass" id="1"></a>
 
 <a href="#1" title="Point 2 Pointer is here" style="left: 73vw;top: 70%;" class="myclass" id="2"></a>
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: I hope that did it, I am new to Stackoverflow, So much to lean. such good guidance. Thanks again.

Comment: @BryanT Welcome dude :)